# where clause after joining the results

Tags: sql-server

It seems where clause applies before join. How to let it filter results after join?

I have my data as:

```
use devBoxDb
go
CREATE TABLE LeftTbl (Id int IDENTITY(1,1),
                      Title varchar(250),
                      Category varchar(250),
                      DateUpdated datetime2(7),
                      CONSTRAINT PK_LeftTbl PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id ASC));
go
insert into LeftTbl(Title,Category,DateUpdated) values
    ('it''s','Accessories','2019-01-02 15:01:03'),
    ('one','TVs','2018-12-13 11:03:46'),
    ('thing','Games','2016-07-17 19:27:23'),
    ('to','Cars','2017-01-12 14:15:17'),
    ('write queries','TVs','1970-01-01 00:00:00');
go
CREATE TABLE RightTbl  (Id int IDENTITY(1,1),
                        EntityId int,
                        DateModified datetime2(7),
                        Reason varchar(250),                        
                        CONSTRAINT PK_RightTbl PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id ASC));

go
insert into RightTbl(EntityId,DateModified,Reason) values
    (4,'2018-12-13 16:40:11','but'),
    (1,'2019-01-09 01:07:29','it''s another'),
    (7,'2019-01-03 13:13:20','to'),
    (2,'2019-01-17 22:41:34','get correct results')
go
```

LeftTbl:

```
Id | Title         | Category    | DateUpdated         |
---|---------------|-------------|---------------------|
1  | it's          | Accessories | 2019-01-02 15:01:03 |
2  | one           | TVs         | 2018-12-13 11:03:46 |
3  | thing         | Games       | 2016-07-17 19:27:23 |
4  | to            | Cars        | 2017-01-12 14:15:17 |
5  | write queries | TVs         | 1970-01-01 00:00:00 |
```

RightTbl:

```
Id | EntityId | DateModified         | Reason 
---|----------|----------------------|----------------------|
1  |  4       | 2018-12-13 16:40:11  | but                  |
2  |  1       | 2019-01-09 01:07:29  | it's another         |
3  |  7       | 2019-01-03 13:13:20  | to                   |
4  |  2       | 2019-01-17 22:41:34  | get correct results  |
```

and my query as:

```
select l.Id, 
       l.Title, 
       l.Category,
       (
           case
               when r.DateModified is null then l.DateUpdated
               when r.DateModified > l.DateUpdated then r.DateModified else l.DateUpdated 
           end 
       ) as DateUpdated
from leftTbl l 
left outer join rightTbl r
on l.Id = r.EntityId
where DateUpdated >= '2018-12-13'
      and DateUpdated < '2018-12-14'
```

Expected:

```
Id | Title   | Category    | DateUpdated                   |
-----------------------------------------------------------|
4  | to      | Cars        | 2018-12-13 16:40:11.0000000   |
```

Actual:

```
Id | Title   | Category    | DateUpdated                  |
----------------------------------------------------------|
2  | one     | TVs         | 2019-01-17 22:41:34.0000000  |
```

Result returns records with `DateUpdated` > `to-date` which brings me to the conclusion that the `where` filter happened before `join`. Is that so or am I (in)sane? How to bring the filtering after join?

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current results and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Something is very wrong with your query. You have from-date and to-date as string literals. Since this is obviously not your real query how do you expect anybody to be able to help? Which table do those two columns belong to? If they are in the second table you have turned your left join into an inner join.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I do hope my edit renders your comment obsolete :)

Comment:  much better!

Comment: Inconsistency in naming hasn't helped you here. If you had consistently used *either* `DateUpdated` *or* `DateModified` as the name of columns containing the date something was changed, it would have been clear that `DateUpdated` in the from clause was a reference to those columns in the *tables*, not a reference to the expression you construct in the `SELECT` clause. (`FROM`/`JOIN` happens before `WHERE`, but `SELECT` happens after, logically)

Answer (score 0):

If your doing a left join and the where clause is on the left joined table you need to move it up to part of the join (like below) because if the where clause has the left join table in it, it sql logically turns that into inner join

```
select Id, 
       Title, 
       Category,
       (
           case
               when r.DateModified is null then l.DateUpdated
               when r.DateModified > l.DateUpdated then r.DateModified else l.DateUpdated 
           end 
       ) as DateUpdated

from leftT l 
left outer join rightT r l.Id = r.EntityId
    -- though not sure what table this is from so maybe add table identifier
    AND DateUpdated >= 'from-date'
    and DateUpdated < 'to-date'
```

Comment: I've made an update to include dummy data if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your Query.

1. Your Table also contain DateUpdated Field and the name you have provided for calculated field also same. In this case calculated field is not taking into consideration.
2. Use this . ( But there is a chance to improve performance in this)

   ```
   Select * from
   (
   select Id, 
      Title, 
      Category,
      (
          case
              when r.DateModified is null then l.DateUpdated
              when r.DateModified > l.DateUpdated then r.DateModified else 
            l.DateUpdated 
          end 
      ) as DateUpdated

   from leftT l 
   left outer join rightT r
   on l.Id = r.EntityId
   ) as tab
   where DateUpdated >= 'from-date'
     and DateUpdated < 'to-date'
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the following does the job. Not quite sure if any performance implications though

```
select l.Id, 
       l.Title, 
       l.Category,
       (
           case
               when r.DateModified is null then l.DateUpdated
               when r.DateModified > l.DateUpdated then r.DateModified else l.DateUpdated 
           end 
       ) as DateUpdated
from leftTbl l 
left outer join rightTbl r
on l.Id = r.EntityId
where IIF(r.DateModified is null or r.DateModified < l.DateUpdated, l.DateUpdated, r.DateModified) 
       between '2018-12-13' and '2018-12-14 23:59:59.9999999'
```

Result:

```
Id | Title   | Category    | DateUpdated                   |
-----------------------------------------------------------|
4  | to      | Cars        | 2018-12-13 16:40:11.0000000   |
```